# Is it okay to replace voltage feedback op-amp with current feedback op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have an LED driving circuit and a photodetecting circuit drawn as below:

**LED driver**

[image]

**Photo detector**

[image]

[TL972IP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl972.pdf) has GBWP of 12 MHz. But my application requires a very high bandwidth up to 30-60 MHz.

So I've been searching an op-amp with high GBWP and found [AD8001ANZ](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8001.pdf). It has a GBWP of 800-880 MHz. Thus, I thought that it is what I am looking for. (Of course I can make bandwidth wider by lowering gain.)

One thing is, I found that it is a *current feedback* op-amp and that CFA's output voltage is deterined based on a current between (+) and (-). In addition, it is good for high frequency application since CFA's gain is independent to frequency.

But I am curious if it is okay to simply replace TL972IP with AD8001ANZ with a few number (resistance, capacitance) changes? but without a big modification on the schematic and a physical layout?

Comment: Have you tried simulating it? The main issue you might have with a CFB opamp is that the negative terminal has a much lower input impedance, but it doesn't look like that'll be an issue in either circuit to me.

Comment: Which simulator can do this? I've installed LTspice a few days ago. And have little knowledge about either circuits and simulators.

Comment: It's not hard to find voltage feedback op-amps with hundreds of MHz GBWP.

Comment: ltspice would be a good start.

Comment: I think, the capacitor C6 may cause problems because safe operation of CFAs requires that the feedback impedance is always larger than a minimuum specified by the manufacturer (mostly 300...500 Ohms).

Comment: How do you know that the LED is fast enough for the higher data speed?

Comment: I think that can be another question. But to see if the LED is fast enough or not, the driver and the receiver should have sufficient time resolution.